# Change nav bar background color when menu is toggled jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make the nav bar when at the top of the page prior to any scrolling allow a change of the background color from transparent to white when the navigation menu is toggled. I have tried adding class .whitenavbar and jQuery to accompany (/*navbar toggle color*/) but it doesn't work and now prevents the menu from toggling at all?

Any help is appreciated!

https://jsfiddle.net/43taovan/

CSS:

```
.navigation{
width:100%;
background: #fff;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.navlist {
display: inline-block;
}
.navlist:after {
content: '';
display: block;
height: 1.5px;
width: 0;
background: transparent;
transition: width .5s ease, background-color .5s ease;
}
.navlist:hover:after {
width: 100%;
background: grey;
}
/*----/----navlist*/

/*global styles*/
 body {
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:1.05em;
font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
}
a {
appearance: none;
font-size:1.05em;
font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Sans-serif;
background:transparent;
color: grey;
border:none;
letter-spacing:0.15em;
text-transform:uppercase;
transition: color 0.5s ease;
list-style: none;
text-decoration: none;
}

/*----/----global styles*/

/*navigation icon*/
 #toggle-menu {
float:right;
display: block;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
padding: 20px;
}
#toggle-menu div {
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
position: relative;
}
.header #toggle-menu span {
display: block;
width: 15px;
height: 3px;
position: absolute;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out, top 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s ease-in-out, top 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out, top 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s;
-webkit-transform-origin: center;
-moz-transform-origin: center;
transform-origin: center;
}
#toggle-menu span.top {
top: 0px;
}
#toggle-menu span.middle {
top: 6px;
}
#toggle-menu span.bottom {
top: 12px;
}
/*----/----navigation icon*/

/*navigation background transition*/
 .bg {
background-color: #fff !important;
border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.show {
opacity: 1;
}
.navfade {
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.header .logo { /* Before scroll */
color: white;
}
.bg .logo { /* After scroll */
color: #545454;
}
.navinstagram {
fill: #fff
}
.bg .navinstagram{
fill: #545454;
}

#toggle-menu span{
background: #fff;
}
.bg #toggle-menu span {
background: #545454;
}

.whitenavbar {
background: #fff;
}
/*----/----navigation background transition*/

/*navigation icon animation*/
 #toggle-menu.menu-is-active span {
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, top 0.2s ease-in-out, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, top 0.2s ease-in-out, opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: transform 0.2s ease-in-out 0.2s, top 0.2s ease-in-out,     opacity 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
#toggle-menu.menu-is-active span.top, #toggle-menu.menu-is-active     span.middle {
top: 6px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#toggle-menu.menu-is-active span.middle {
opacity: 0;
}
#toggle-menu.menu-is-active span.bottom {
top: 6px;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
/*----/----navigation icon animation*/

/*Nav Bar*/
 .header {
/*border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);*/
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 99999;
background-color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
/*background: none;*/
}
.nav {
display: none;
list-style-type: none;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
left:0;
top: 55px;
border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
border-top: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
cursor: pointer;
color: #545454;
font-size:.8em;
letter-spacing:0.05em;
}
.nav li {
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
background: #fff;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.seemore {
display: inline-block;
padding-right: 20px;
}
#navpromo {
border-top: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
padding-bottom: 10px;
background: #ffffff;
}
.instbtn-cont {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn {
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  color: grey;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn:hover {
  border: none;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn:hover .line-1 {
  -webkit-animation: move1 1500ms infinite ease;
      animation: move1 1500ms infinite ease;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn:hover .line-2 {
  -webkit-animation: move2 1500ms infinite ease;
      animation: move2 1500ms infinite ease;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn:hover .line-3 {
  -webkit-animation: move3 1500ms infinite ease;
      animation: move3 1500ms infinite ease;
}
.instbtn-cont .instbtn:hover .line-4 {
  -webkit-animation: move4 1500ms infinite ease;
      animation: move4 1500ms infinite ease;
}
.instbtn-cont .line-1 {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: grey;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.instbtn-cont .line-2 {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: grey;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.instbtn-cont .line-3 {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: grey;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.instbtn-cont .line-4 {
content: "";
display: block;
position: absolute;
height: 1px;
background-color: grey;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
}

@-webkit-keyframes move1 {
  0% {
height: 100%;
bottom: 0;
  }
  54% {
height: 0;
bottom: 100%;
  }
  55% {
height: 0;
bottom: 0;
  }
  100% {
height: 100%;
bottom: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes move1 {
  0% {
height: 100%;
bottom: 0;
  }
  54% {
height: 0;
bottom: 100%;
  }
  55% {
height: 0;
bottom: 0;
  }
  100% {
height: 100%;
bottom: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move2 {
  0% {
width: 0;
left: 0;
  }
  50% {
width: 100%;
left: 0;
  }
  100% {
width: 0;
left: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes move2 {
  0% {
width: 0;
left: 0;
  }
  50% {
width: 100%;
left: 0;
  }
  100% {
width: 0;
left: 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move3 {
  0% {
height: 100%;
top: 0;
  }
  54% {
height: 0;
top: 100%;
  }
  55% {
height: 0;
top: 0;
  }
  100% {
height: 100%;
top: 0;
  }
}
@keyframes move3 {
  0% {
height: 100%;
top: 0;
  }
  54% {
height: 0;
top: 100%;
  }
  55% {
height: 0;
top: 0;
  }
  100% {
height: 100%;
top: 0;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move4 {
0% {
width: 0;
right: 0;
}
55% {
width: 100%;
right: 0;
  }
  100% {
width: 0;
right: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes move4 {
  0% {
width: 0;
right: 0;
  }
  55% {
width: 100%;
right: 0;
  }
  100% {
width: 0;
right: 100%;
  }
}


/*----/----Nav Bar*/

/*in*/
 .in {
float:left;
display: inline-block;
width: 25px;
height: 25px;
padding: 15px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff;
font-size:.8em;
letter-spacing:0.05em;
border-top: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
/*----/----in*/

/*logo*/
 .logo {
position: absolute;
left: 47%;
display: inline-block;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
padding: 18px;
cursor: pointer;
color: #fff;
font-size:.8em;
letter-spacing:0.05em;
}
/*----/----logo*/

/****landscape****/
@media only screen and (max-width: 555px) { 
.nav li{
display: block;
padding: 30px;
}
}
/*----/----Landscape*/
```

jQuery

```
/*navigation icon animation*/
var trigger = 'X';

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$('#toggle-menu').click(function () {
    trigger = 'X';
    $(this).toggleClass('menu-is-active')

});

/* click outside of nav to trigger navigation icon animation*/
$(document).click(function () {


    if (trigger == 'X') {
        $("#toggle-menu").toggleClass();
        trigger = 'ham';
    }



});
$("nav").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});

/*----/----navigation icon animation*/

/*toggle menu*/
jQuery("#toggle-menu").click(function () {
    jQuery(".nav").slideToggle();

});
/* click outside of nav to close toggle*/
$(document).click(function () {
    $(".nav").hide();
});
$("#toggle-menu").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
/*----/----toggle menu*/

/*navbar toggle color*/
 $("#toggle-menu").click(function (e) {
  $(".nav").addClass(".whitenavbar");
  $('.nav').addClass('navfade');
    }
    else {
        $('.nav').removeClass(".whitenavbar");
    }
});
/*----/----navbar toggle color*/

/*Jump Scroll*/
$(function () {
    var $window = $(window),
        $document = $(document),
        transitionSupported = typeof document.body.style.transitionProperty === "string",
        scrollTime = 1; // scroll time in seconds

    $(document).on("click", "a[href*=#]:not([href=#])", function (e) {
        var target, avail, scroll, deltaScroll;

        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, "") ==     this.pathname.replace(/^\//, "") && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $("[id=" +     this.hash.slice(1) + "]");

            if (target.length) {
                avail = $document.height() - $window.height();

                if (avail > 0) {
                    scroll = target.offset().top;

                    if (scroll > avail) {
                        scroll = avail;
                    }
                } else {
                    scroll = 0;
                }

                deltaScroll = $window.scrollTop() - scroll;

                if (!deltaScroll) {
                    return; // do nothing
                }
                e.preventDefault();

                if (transitionSupported) {
                    $("html").css({
                        "margin-top": deltaScroll + "px",
                            "transition": scrollTime + "s ease-in-out"
                    }).data("transitioning", scroll);
                } else {

                    $("html, body").stop(true, true)
                        .animate({
                        scrollTop: scroll + "px"
                    }, scrollTime * 1000);

                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    if (transitionSupported) {
        $("html").on("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd     oTransitionEnd", function (e) {
            var $this = $(this),
                scroll = $this.data("transitioning");

            if (e.target === e.currentTarget && scroll) {
                $this.removeAttr("style").removeData("transitioning");

                $("html, body").scrollTop(scroll);
            }
        });
    }
});
/*----/----Jump Scroll*/

/*contact let me know toggle*/ 
$("#container").hide();

$("#button").on('click', function() {

    if($("#button").val() == 'thank you')
        return false;

if($("#container").is(":visible"))
return false;

$("#container").toggle();
this.value = this.value == 'send me a message' ? 'contact' : 'send me a     message';
});

 $("#button2").on('click', function(e) {
    $("#container").toggle();
    $("#button").val('thank you');
 });     
/*----/-----contact let me know toggle*/

/*navigation background fade in fade out */
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var dist = $('#panel2').offset().top;
    console.log(dist);
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > dist) {
        $('.header').addClass('bg');
        $('.header').addClass('navfade');
    }
    else {
        $('.header').removeClass('bg');
    }


});


$('.scroll').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
    }, 1500);
});

/*----/-----navigation background fade in fade out */

});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
<div class="navbar">
<a href="" class="in" style="display: inline-block;"> 
<svg class="navinstagram" version="1.1" id="Layer_1"      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
viewBox="0 0 155.2 144" style="enable-background:new 0 0 155.2 144;"      xml:space="preserve">
<path  d="M42.7,122.7H21.3V54h21.4V122.7z M32,44.6c-6.8,0-12.4-5.6- 12.4-12.4c0-6.8,5.5-12.4,12.4-12.4
c6.8,0,12.4,5.5,12.4,12.4C44.4,39,38.9,44.6,32,44.6z M122.7,122.7h- 21.3V89.3c0-8-0.1-18.2-11.1-18.2c-11.1,0-12.8,8.7-12.8,17.6
v34H56.1V54h20.5v9.4h0.3c2.8-5.4,9.8-11.1,20.2- 11.1c21.6,0,25.6,14.2,25.6,32.7V122.7z"/>
<g>
<path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M151.9,120c0.7-0.1,1-0.5,1-1.1c0-0.8-     0.5-1.1-1.4-1.1H150v4h0.6V120h0.7l0,0l1.1,1.7h0.6L151.9,120
L151.9,120z M151.3,119.6h-0.7v- 1.4h0.9c0.4,0,0.9,0.1,0.9,0.6C152.4,119.5,151.9,119.6,151.3,119.6z"/>
<path style="fill:#FFFFFF;" d="M151.3,116c-2.1,0-3.8,1.7- 3.8,3.8c0,2.1,1.7,3.8,3.8,3.8c2.1,0,3.8-1.7,3.8-3.8
C155.2,117.6,153.5,116,151.3,116z M151.3,123.1c-1.8,0-3.3-1.4-3.3- 3.3c0-1.9,1.4-3.3,3.3-3.3c1.8,0,3.3,1.4,3.3,3.3
C154.6,121.7,153.2,123.1,151.3,123.1z"/>
</g>
</svg>
</a>

<a href="" class="logo logocolorchng" style="display: inline- block;">Logo     </a>

<a id="toggle-menu">
<div> 
<span class="top"></span>
<span class="middle"></span>
<span class="bottom"></span>
</div>
</a>

</div>
<div class="nav">

<div class="navigation">
<ul>
<li class="navlist"><a href="" style="display: inline-block; width:100%;">Home</a></li>            
<li class="navlist"><a href="#panel2" style="display: inline-block;     width:100%;">Work</a></li>
<li class="navlist"><a href="#wrapper" style="display: inline-block;  width:100%;">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="navpromo">
        <ul>
            <li class="seemore">Want to see more? Check out my    instagram!</li>
            </li>

            <div class='instbtn-cont'>
<a class='instbtn' href='#'>
Instagram
<span class='line-1'></span>
<span class='line-2'></span>
<span class='line-3'></span>
<span class='line-4'></span>
</a>
</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dude firsty you check all brackets closed and opened in proper manner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following define your whitenavbar css after the the css you have already defined for the element.It is working for header. If you want to apply to other element then change accordingly. if you change .nav background it would not be visible. Next option is to change .navigation

```
/*toggle menu*/

jQuery("#toggle-menu").click(function () {
    jQuery(".nav").slideToggle();
    if($("div.header").hasClass("whitenavbar") == false){
        $("div.header").addClass("whitenavbar");
    }else{
    $("div.header").removeClass("whitenavbar");
    }

});
```

css notice it is after .header{} css

```
    /*Nav Bar*/
     .header {
        /*border-bottom: 0.5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.2);*/
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 99999;
        background-color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
        /*background: none;*/
    }
    .whitenavbar {

        background: teal;
    }
```

Comment: This works thank you. I changed the background color to white and also add classes to adjust the text and iconography colors to grey.      jQuery("#toggle-menu").click(function () {
    jQuery(".nav").slideToggle();
    if($("div.header").hasClass("whitenavbar") == false){
        $("div.header").addClass("whitenavbar navfade bg");
    }else{
    $("div.header").removeClass("whitenavbar bg");
    }

});

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think maybe the reason it isn't toggling is because of the else statement because it looks like when it's clicked you're adding those classes, and if it's not clicked you're removing them, but if it isn't clicked you aren't adding them in the first place (if that makes sense), and maybe this could be why it isn't toggling.

I'm getting an error when I try to run the JSFiddle (I could just be clicking the wrong thing) but if you want the nav bar to turn white when it's clicked you could just change the CSS, and because changing the CSS is a simpler solution it might have less of a chance of causing a problem with the toggle in the first place.

```
$(".nav").css("background", "white");
```

Comment: Here is an updated JSFiddle without error https://jsfiddle.net/43taovan/7/. I replaced the jQuery with the above code but it doesn't work?

Comment: Wait, you're trying to change the bar at the top that says "LOGO" to white right?

Comment: I put ".nav" in $(".nav").css("background", "white"); because that's what was already there when you were using the add class function, I'm just trying to make sure I understand which part you want to be white because maybe that's not the right class to change the CSS for.

Comment: If you're trying to change the bar at the top to white it would have to be ".header" instead of ".nav", and if that's what you want to be white adding classes might work if you replace ".nav" in your original code with ".header". In the JSFiddle I replaced it and the  bar at the top turned white (disappeared) when I toggled.